# Ayuda obteniendo datos desde JS en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estoy viendo un curso de JS, y va por la parte de AJAX, entiendo del empaquetado y todo, la unica duda que tengo es a la hora de validarlo en php`$usuario = isset($_GET["usuario"]) ? $_GET["usuario"]: $_POST["usuario"];`

Mi duda ahi es con el ?, se que es una manera mas corta de escribir el if else, pero aun asi no lo entiendo, la variable usuario va a ser lo mismo que tenga isset("$_GET["usuario"]) si es que devuelve true, es decir que tiene algo, en otro caso $_GET["usuario"] = $_POST["usuario"]??? ahi no entiendo, como obtengo el $_POST["usuario"] si lo estoy enviendo mediante get desde el formulario, espero me entienda, si no expliquenme que esta haciendo esa parte... gracias

Comment: veelo de la siguiente manera, este es el llamado if ternario. 

[CONDICIÓN] [ENTONCES (?)] TRUE : FALSE  

si tu [condición] es verdadera [ENTONCES ?] hago TRUE [Sino : ]HAGO false

Comment: Sintaxis:        resultado =  (condicion) ? valor1 : valor2;

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tengas dudas con la forma abreviada del `if`, te sugiero escribir el mismo pero en su forma extendida (la clásica), sólo para clarificar las opciones, luego lo borras. En tu caso:

`if (isset($_GET["usuario"]))`
`{ $usuario = $_GET["usuario"]; }`
`else`
`{ $usuario = $_POST["usuario"]; }`

Answer (score 0):

A ver, voy a intentar explicarlo de la mejor forma que pueda.
Primero,

```
$usuario = isset($_GET["usuario"]) ? $_GET["usuario"]: $_POST["usuario"];
```

Se puede traducir como:

```
if(isset($_GET['usuario'])){
     $usuario = $_GET['usuario'];
}else{
     $usaurio = $_POST['usuario']:
}
```

Lo cual quiere decir que si existe el valor 'usuario' dentro de la superglobal `$_GET[]`, `$usuario` tomará ese valor, y que si no existe, `$usuario` tomará el valor que guarde la superglobal `$_POST[]` en la posicion 'usuario', donde `?` equivaldría al `if` como tal, y la condición va antes del `if` en este caso.

En esa declaración hay un posible error, y es que deberías contemplar la posibilidad de que no existiese la posición 'usuario', tanto en `$_POST[]` como en `$_GET[]`. Eso traducido en un operador ternario sería:

```
$usuario = isset($_GET['usuario']) ? $_GET['usuario'] : (isset($_POST['usuario']) ? $_POST['usuario'] : [VALOR POR DEFECTO/ O DE ERROR]);
```

De esta forma evitarías el error Undefined Index que mostraría tu php al ejecutar el código sin `$_GET['usuario']` o `$_POST['usuario']`.

Comment: hola, es decir, el $_POST["usuario"] es por si envio el formulario mediante el metodo post y no get?

Comment: exacto, es sólo por evitar errores de php, si estas 100% seguro de que va a llegar el dato siempre por $_GET, no hace realmente hacer la comparación, pero siempre está bien, por si algún dia cambias el formulario no tener que tocar el php